# How to get the max value of an alphanumeric column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I Have a PostgreSQL database, there's a table named "labels".

Inside labels there's a column named "label" with a lot of values with the format 3 letters "GCS" and then numbers...
For example: GCS1234, GCS9999, GCS14500

This should be an incremental table, where every time a new label is created, a query should take the max value and then add +1.

The former programmer's solution was to count total values that would be like GCS (disregarding the number) and to the count total add 1.

I have to make a cleanup of the database, and this won't work for me. Instead I would have to get the max value and add 1, and here is where I get the issue:

```
SELECT MAX(label) from labels where label ilike '%GCS%'
```

The result of this query is GCS9999 when the real max value at this moment is GCS14500

I found a temporal solution to get the max value by doing:

```
`SELECT MAX(label) from labels where label ilike '%GCS%' and lenght (label)>'7'`
```

but this is just a patch, since at the moment this column values reaches something over GCS99999, the max value will be again GCS99999.

So I'm looking for a permanent solution to this, a way that I could get the max value of this alphanumeric column keeping in mind the format of the labels

Comment: Well `max(<some_string>)` is going to find `max` based on string sorting rules not numeric sorting so that is why you are getting `GCS9999`. One solution would be too split into two columns, one for the prefix `GCS` and the other for the numbers. You can do that with `select substr ('GCS14500', 4)::integer; 14500`, which you  could also use now to get the numeric part of the string as a number.

Comment: Using `max+1` is a poor choice of assigning a value. In a heavily used multiple user environment it is a virtual guarantee you will get a duplicate. Postgres is a [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) system . This means 2 users can get the same `max` value and generate a duplicate value, At a minimum you need a unique constraint on that column and retry functionally in you app when the constraint is violated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functions inside your aggregate function calls.  In this case, substring (starting with the 4th character) is what you want, I believe.  You also need the sort to be numeric instead of alpha, so you cast the result of the substring function to int inside the max() function.

```
create table simple(my_column varchar(12));

insert into simple values ('GCS1234'), ('GCS9999'), ('GCS14500');

select max(substring(my_column,4)::int)
from simple;

>> 14500
```

Of course you want the GCS back, so you can add that to the front.

```
select 'GCS'||max(substring(my_column,4)::int)
from simple;

>> GCS14500
```